# Replacing 'View Basket' Text in WooCommerce with Custom Text Using Code Snippets Plugin

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, elementor

I have a WooCommerce website and I want to replace the text "View Basket" with a different text. I have searched online for solutions, but most of them only provide instructions for renaming "View Cart." Can anyone provide me with a code snippet that I can apply using a code snippets plugin?

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot]